# AWS MultipartUploadException for file over 5GB in size

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

This is the error when trying to copy a file >5GB on S3 from one folder to another in the same bucket.
[S3Client::copy()](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.9.2/src/S3/S3Client.php#L467)

```
Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException: An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload. The following parts had errors:
- Part 1: Error executing "UploadPartCopy" on "https://example.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder/6gbfile.txt?*"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://example.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder2/6gbfile.txt?*` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>folder%252F6gbfile.txt%252Fen (truncated...)
 NoSuchKey (client): The specified key does not exist. - <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>folder%252F6gbfile.txt</Key><RequestId>*</RequestId><HostId>*</HostId></Error>
```

I've renamed some parts to hide private info. and only shown the first occurance of the error, it is repeated for over 400 parts.

It only happens for files greater than 5GB. Works on windows localhost running EasyPHP but not on a Windows EC2 instance.

- AWS SDK: 3.154
- PHP: 7.2.34
- CURL: 7.67.0
- OpenSSl: 1.1.1g

EDIT: This error is also logged from the same request multiple times

```
- Part 706: Error executing \"UploadPartCopy\" on \"https:\/\/example.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/folder\/6gbfile.txt?*\"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: C:\\PHP7234\\cacert.pem\n  CApath: none (see https:\/\/curl.haxx.se\/libcurl\/c\/libcurl-errors.html)\n
```

Comment: You are using curl instead of an AWS client like AWSCLI? where is the code that produces that error?

Comment: ```$response = $s3Client->copy($srcBucket, $srcFile, $trgBucket, $trgFile);```

It's a function in the AWS PHP SDK